# Easiest way to instantiate a transceiver in Quartus to avoid unused channel degradation

Tags: fpga, quartus

[This answer in the altera knowledge base](https://www.altera.com/support/support-resources/knowledge-base/solutions/rd06092016_720.html) indicates that the TX channels on the Arria 10 degrade over time if left unused. I have added the recommended assignment to my QSF file, but it has no effect if I don't already use some transceivers:

```
Warning(18584): There are no transceiver channels used in the design. You must use or instantiate at least 1 transceiver channel to preserve the rest of the unused channels.
```

I'm just trying out some very simple examples to start with and am trying to find my way around Quartus. How can I instantiate a transceiver with minimum fuss so I don't ruin the boards?

Comment: Which version of quartus are you using?

Comment: That answer also says the problem doesn't exist if you're using a version of Quartus newer than 16.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that adding an IOPLL counts, even though the number of unused channels stays the same:

```
iopll iopll_i (
  .locked(),
  .refclk(FPGA_CLK2K_P),
  .rst(~A10_RST_L),
  .outclk_0(clk)
);
```

Routing the reference clock through an IOPLL with multiply/divide settings of 1/1 does not change the clock frequency but allows the transceiver preservation settings to take effect.